# Export DB2 to XML File

Tags: xml, shell, db2, ksh

I'm familiar with exporting to csv using the EXPORT TO *filename* OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL *SQL* command. To export to csv. That works fine.

To export to XML, I've tried commands that I found in the IBM documentation such as...

```
EXPORT TO *filename* OF DEL XMLSAVESCHEMA *SQL*
or
EXPORT TO *filename* OF DEL XML TO *filename?* 
   XMLFILE xmldocs XMLSAVESCHEMA *SQL*
```

The error I'm receiving is below.

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "XMLSAVESCHEMA" was found following
>   "DEL". Expected tokens may include:  "SELECT".  SQLSTATE=42601
>   DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.

Comment: Need your Db2-server version and platform (Z/os  i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows).

Comment: See examples here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/r0024040.html

Comment: the 'XML TO' argument should be a directory(not a file). Both of the syntax types mentioned in the question work fine for me with DB2 LUW v11.1. Usually you want  `modified by xmlinsepfiles` else all the XML goes into a single file, which might not be what you want.  Hence asking for your Db2-server platform and version.